# Multiple tags with JavaScript off

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, tags, javascript

I'm using Stack Overflow with JavaScript off in [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) 11.61.

I tried to submit a question with two sets of tags, entered like this:

```
[user-accounts][discussion]
```

However, when I submitted the question and after I'd gone through the [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA), I was presented with these two errors:

> - must include one of these tags -- 'bug feature-request discussion support'
> - users with less than 500 reputation can't create new tags. The tag 'user-accountsdiscussion' is new. Try using an existing tag instead.

It appears Stack Overflow stripped the square brackets from my tags. [The documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) doesn't state that anything special is require to concatenate tags together, so I didn't go with spaces or commas or the like.

I'd posit that non-delimited tags should work fine given the square brackets themselves act as delimiters.

Comment: The editing help doesn't say that you can use brackets to delimit tags. The `[tag:foobar]` syntax works only in text body.

Comment: @Juhana - So what do you use to delimit? The help certainly doesn't say and it's a reasonable UI expectation that tag syntax in the tag box remains the same as tag syntax in the text box.

Comment: When you start writing tags the help text on the right side of the page says *"delimit tags by space, semicolon, or comma."*

Comment: @Juhana - That only happens with JavaScript on. The entire point of this question is that its with JS off, and there is no such text in that situation.

Comment: I'm not sure anymore what the question/suggestion is. Is it that the brackets should work as delimiters, or that the delimiters aren't described in the help, or something else?

Comment: @Juhana - Both. The help tells you to use square brackets but it doesn't say they can't be used in the tags box; I believe it's a reasonable UI expection that if they work in one they should work in another. If square brackets were allowed in the tag-text option then they'd also be self-delimiting.

Comment: This is not a bug, it's absolutely by-design...use a space to delimit tags, it's a very simple format.  If you want something *else* to happen to support this (I have to be honest we don't really strive to support the non-JS case that much, it's very rare and I haven't seen a report of this being confusing before), that's a [feature-request].

Answer (score 4):

When you load the site with JavaScript disabled, there's a big red header at the top that reads,

> Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled

Among many, many other helpful features, JavaScript enables that handy bit of help text that tells you how to format tags. Of course, now you know that you need a space or a semicolon or a comma, so you won't need the help text - but next time you encounter a problem using Stack Overflow, consider enabling JavaScript first - you might just encounter a bit of helpful instruction.